# SUMIFS formula backwards

Tags: excel, xlsx, sumifs

In the example simple spreadsheet in the link below, I have `SUMIF`s in `A13` and `COUNTIF`s in `B13`, which calculate values from the data section in rows 2 through 8. I want to show in `C13` the names from column A that matched the criteria of `COUNTIF`s in cell `B13`. How do I do that?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ar8KQVkas0kimWOEsgJsuIfPHQOCc9hiUHadmOpaZ7k/edit#gid=0

In the example spreadsheet, cell `C13` contains the desired text value of the 3 "mesta" which I need a mechanism to calculate.

Comment: You cannot dynamically concatenate an unknown number of text strings together into a single cell using native Excel functions. You would have to either a) write a formula that could conceivably accommodate the largest possible number of matches and only fill in the matches that worked or b) write a VBA user Defined Function (aka UDF) that loops through the data and provides a concatenated string of the matches. There are dozens of the examples of the latter on this site. I've written at least several. e.g. [Conditional Concatenation](http://tinyurl.com/mlb6brk)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to create "worker" columns, and if your number of rows is not too large (especially no more than 255), then you can calculate C13 in an inelegant manner:

1. In cell G2 add formula: =IF(AND(B2=1,C2=1,D2=1,E2=0),A2&", ","")
2. Fill-down G2 into G3 through G8
3. In Cell G13 add formula: =CONCATENATE(G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8)
4. In Cell C13 add formula: =IF(LEN(G13)>2,LEFT(G13,LEN(G13)-2),"")

Its not the most agile and flexible way to do it, but if your dataset is small and you don't mind adding a worker column (and hiding it if necessary), this will work.